# Get list of variables whose name matches a certain pattern

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

In bash

```
echo ${!X*}
```

will print all the names of the variables whose name starts with 'X'.
Is it possible to get the same with an arbitrary pattern, e.g. get all the names of the variables whose name contains an 'X' in any position?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the builtin command compgen:

```
compgen -A variable | grep X
```

Comment: (+1) This works with local variables as well. This compgen has been today's revelation - I think I should *study* all bash builtins...

Comment: @AlexanderMills it works for bash. Checked with bash-3.2 on macos.

Answer (score 17):

This should do it:

```
env | grep ".*X.*"
```

Edit: sorry, that looks for X in the value too.
This version only looks for X in the var name

```
env | awk -F "=" '{print $1}' | grep ".*X.*"
```

As Paul points out in the comments, if you're looking for local variables too, env needs to be replaced with set:

```
set | awk -F "=" '{print $1}' | grep ".*X.*"
```

Comment: Only gets environment variables, not local ones.  Although using "set" instead of "env" might work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about set, I usually "export" any vars I'm interested in so I only use env.

Comment: set also print out function, not only local variables and environment variables

Comment: Use `(set -o posix ; set)` instead, that'll remove the functions from the list.

Comment: That will not work with grep, as variable content will also be in the output, and that can contain newlines.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest might be to do a

```
printenv |grep D.*=
```

The only difference is it also prints out the variable's values.

Answer (score 3):

This will search for X only in variable names and output only matching variable names:

```
set | grep -oP '^\w*X\w*(?==)'
```

or for easier editing of searched pattern

```
set | grep -oP '^\w*(?==)' | grep X
```

or simply (maybe more easy to remember)

```
set | cut -d= -f1 | grep X
```

If you want to match X inside variable names, but output in name=value form, then:

```
set | grep -P '^\w*X\w*(?==)'
```

and if you want to match X inside variable names, but output only value, then:

```
set | grep -P '^\w*X\w*(?==)' | grep -oP '(?<==).*'
```

Comment: this needs to note that -P may require additional library to be installed on some older platforms

Comment: I didn't know Mac OS X was that old 

Answer (score 3):

Enhancing Johannes Schaub - litb answer removing fork/exec in modern bash we could do

```
compgen -A variable  -X '!*X*'
```

i.e an X in any position in the variable list.

Answer (score 1):

```
env | awk -F= '{if($1 ~ /X/) print $1}'
```

Comment: I needed to get the values also. By simply removing the `$1` from your solution, my problem was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511937/6219628)'s answer:

There is a shortcut for `-A variable` and a flag to include a pattern:

```bash
compgen -v -X '!*SEARCHED*'
```

- `-v` is a shortcut for `-A variable`
- `-X` takes a pattern that must not be matched.

Hence `-v -X '!*SEARCHED*'` reads as:

- variables that do not, not match "anything + SEARCHED + anything"

Which is equivalent to:

- variables that do match "anything + SEARCHED + anything"

---

The question explicitly mentions "variables" but I think it's safe to say that many people will be looking for "custom declared things" instead.

**But neither functions nor aliases are listed by `-v`**.

If you are looking for variables, functions and aliases, you should use the following instead:

```bash
compgen -av -A function -X '!*SEARCHED*'
# equivalent to:
compgen -A alias -A variable -A function -X '!*SEARCHED*'
```

And if you only search for things **that start with a PREFIX**, `compgen` does that for you by default:

```bash
compgen -v PREFIX
```

You may of course adjust the options as needed, and the official doc will help you: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

to expand [Phi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69432568/3559739) and [Johannes Schaub - litb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511937/3559739) answers for the following use case:

*print contents of all environment variables whose names match a pattern as strings which can be reused in other (Bash) scripts, i.e. with all special characters properly escaped and the whole contents quoted*

In case you have the following environment variables

```
export VAR_WITH_QUOTES=\"FirstName\ LastName\"\ \<firstname.lastname@example.com\>
export VAR_WITH_WHITESPACES=" 
    a bc
"
export VAR_EMPTY=""
export VAR_WITH_QUOTES_2=\"\'
```

then the following snippet prints all `VAR*` environment variables in reusable presentation:

```
for var in $(compgen -A export -X '!VAR*'); do
  printf "%s=%s\n" "$var" "${!var@Q}"
done
```

Snippet is is valid for Bash 4+.

The output is as follows, please note output for newlines, empty variables and variables which contain quotation characters:

```
VAR_EMPTY=''
VAR_WITH_QUOTES='"FirstName LastName" <firstname.lastname@example.com>'
VAR_WITH_QUOTES_2='"'\'''
VAR_WITH_WHITESPACES=$' \n\ta bc\n'
```

This also relates to the question [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379181/65837)