# How do I output env as a runnable shell script

Tags: bash

You can trivially output your environment as a runnable shell script using

```
env > my_env
```

... later in another script ...

```
set -a
source my_env
```

This works for the most trivial cases, but fails if any special chars or spaces are in env.

How can I fix the above script so it works with stuff like `a='"'"'"` ?

Comment: Running that script doesn't do very much, though, given as as soon as it's done running it exits, and its parent's environment changes not a bit. `source my_env` makes more sense, but that doesn't require `chmod +x`.

Comment: good point removing the +x as its noise

Answer (score 4):

Use `set` instead of `env`:

```
○ → set | grep LESS
LESS=-R
LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'

○ → env | grep LESS
LESS=-R
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
```

Thanks to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305273/93180) we can do this to get JUST environment variables as follows:

```
○ → (set -o posix; set) | grep LESS
LESS=-R
LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
```

---

Try this behemoth which should print just the difference from a "pristine" shell. YMMV:

```
diff --old-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format= --new-line-format= \
    <(bash -c 'set -o posix; set' | sort) \
    <(env -i bash -c 'set -o posix; set' | sort)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following uses bash's `printf %q` to escape values correctly regardless of their content. It's guaranteed to handle literally any value possible -- quotes, newlines, etc -- so long as the shell sourcing its output is bash, and so long as the operating system in use supports the `/proc/self/environ` facility first provided by Linux to emit the contents of the environment as a NUL-delimited stream. It uses special quoting forms such as `$'\n'` as and where appropriate, so its output may not be honored by pure POSIX interpreters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' kvname; do
  k=${kvname%%=*}
  v=${kvname#*=}
  printf '%q=%q\n' "$k" "$v"
done </proc/self/environ
```

Note that you'll want to *source* the output, not run it as an external executable, if you want your current shell's environment to change. If you don't want to `set -a` before sourcing, add a leading `export` to the format string.

Comment: I just tried out (set -o posix; export) and it seems to do the trick as well, is this going to explode on me?

Comment: I doubt you need the `set -o posix` there, actually; `export` alone is probably fine. The one thing that the above code does better than the natively shell-based solutions is exposing environment variables that *aren't* also valid shell variables (for instance, when set by non-shell languages with non-shell-legal names), but the way those behave is... highly variable anyhow.

Comment: @SamSaffron, ...that said, reading the documentation for `export` (or, if you want to be more explicit, `export -p`), I don't see it _guaranteeing_ that its output is shell-safe. `printf '%q'` *guarantees* safety. On the other hand, relying on `/proc` is guaranteed to reduce your portability, so this approach definitely has its pitfalls, and the implementation in the versions of bash I'm looking at appear to be entirely safe despite not guaranteeing this in documentation.

Comment: @SamSaffron, why don't you add `export -p` as its own answer? You'd have my upvote.

Comment: k I added it, deployed that in my docker build earlier today and all seems happy.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution seems to be

```
export -p > my_env
```