# Print all variables used within a bash script

Tags: bash

Is there any way to print all the variables declared and used within a Bash script?

For example `printf "%s\n" "${FUNCNAME[@]}"` will print the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack.

Ex: This is my script content (there must be a lot of declared variables):

```
#!/bin/bash

say_hello() {
    name="$1"
    echo "Hello $name"
}

my_name="Luis Daniel"
my_age="29"

say_hello "$my_name"
```

Then, I need to log something like this:

```
my_name = Luis Daniel
my_age = 29
name = Luis Daniel
```

Comment: Look at the [set](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html) or [env](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env) commands.

Comment: No, "set" shows a lot of information that I do not need, I just need to register in a log file all the variables declared and used in the script

Comment: Dude, you didn't specify that in your question.  You have *MANY* options: including "set", "env", "printenv", "declare -x", etc. etc.  You can also use any of these options *IN CONJUNCTION* with other commands like "sed", "grep" and/or "awk".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list variables declared in script in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305237/how-to-list-variables-declared-in-script-in-bash). Use `( set -o posix ; set )` or `declare -p`.