# how to print all variables in bash script?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=1
var2='two'
third='cat'
abcd='dog'
.
.
.
.
something='else'
env
```

Now I want print all variables declared inside my script.
I tried `env`, but yea... it prints environment vars not my local ones..
Also `cat /proc/$$/environ` doesnot give me what I want as its equal to `env`.
Running my script with more debug info `bash -x ./myscript.sh` does not suit me.
Is there any trick to list all vars with their values?

Comment: use comand `set`

Comment: There's nothing that will just print the variables defined in the script. `set` will print them, but it also prints all the built-in variables and inherited environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459116

```
#!/bin/bash

set_before=$( set -o posix; set | sed -e '/^_=*/d' )

var1=1
var2='two'
third='cat'
abcd='dog'
something='else'

set_after=$( set -o posix; unset set_before; set | sed -e '/^_=/d' )
diff  <(echo "$set_before") <(echo "$set_after") | sed -e 's/^> //' -e '/^[[:digit:]].*/d'
```

Comment: If this is answered in another question, just flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you might not need to save the "before" `set` output and then compare it with an "after" output.

If all your variables have some basic pattern, a `set | grep` may be enough.

The built-in variables all have uppercase names. I always start my script variable names in lowercase. So a simple

```bash
set | grep '^[a-z].*='
```

lists all the variables defined so far in the script.

This would also parse functions, but since `set` prints them indented, these lines will not start with a lowercase letter and will be ignored.

If you don't want the functions to also go through `grep`, use the Posix option as in all other answers:

```bash
( set -o posix; set | grep '^[a-z].*=' )
```