# values to array from variable names with pattern

Tags: bash

I have an unknown number of variable names with the pattern rundate*. For example, `rundate=180618 && rundate2=180820`. I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511694/get-list-of-variables-whose-name-matches-a-certain-pattern) that I can send multiple variable names to a third variable: `` alld=(`echo "${!rundate*}"`) `` and while attempting to solve my problem, I figured out how to send multiple variable indices to a third variable: `` alld_indices=(`echo "${!alld[@]}"`) ``. But, how do I send multiple values to my third variable: `alld_values` such that `echo ${alld_values[@]}` gives `180618 180820`. I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921279/how-to-get-a-variable-value-if-variable-name-is-stored-as-string) how I can get the first value: `` firstd_value=(`echo "${!alld}"`) ``. I suspect, I've seen the answer already in my searching but did not realize it. Happy to delete my question if that is the case. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Paul Hodges and Charles Duffy. All four answers worked well. Really good detail and context, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set up some test data
rundate="180618"
rundate1="180820"
rundate2="Values With Spaces Work Too"

# If we know all values are numeric, we can use a regular indexed array
# otherwise, the below would need to be ''declare -A alld=( )''
alld=( )                       # initialize an array
for v in "${!rundate@}"; do    # using @ instead of * avoids IFS-related bugs
  alld[${v#rundate}]=${!v}     # populate the array, using varname w/o prefix as key
done

# print our results
printf 'Full array definition:\n   '
declare -p alld                 # emits code that, if run, will redefine the array
echo; echo "Indexes only:"
printf ' - %s\n' "${!alld[@]}"  # "${!varname[@]}" expands to the list of keys
echo; echo "Values only:"
printf ' - %s\n' "${alld[@]}"   # "${varname[@]}" expands to the list of values
```

...properly emits as output:

```
Full array definition:
   declare -a alld=([0]="180618" [1]="180820" [2]="Values With Spaces Work Too")

Indexes only:
 - 0
 - 1
 - 2

Values only:
 - 180618
 - 180820
 - Values With Spaces Work Too
```

...as you can see running at https://ideone.com/yjSD1J

Comment: something maybe wrong with the associative array suggestion. I was trying to validate with `rundate="180618" && rundate1="180820" && declare -A alld=( ) && for v in "${!rundate@}"; do alld[${v#rundate}]=${!v}; done` but got -bash: alld[${v#rundate}]: bad array subscript

Comment: Right, that's because an empty string isn't a valid key. If you're going the associative route, just make it `$v`, not `${v#rundate}`. There's a reason I only put the `#rundate` back in when changing the code to use an indexed array (in which the empty string evaluates to `0`) instead of an associative one (in which it's invalid).

Answer (score 1):

`eval` in a loop will do it.

```
$: for v in ${!rundate*}
>  do eval "alld_values+=( \$$v )"
>  done
$: echo "${alld_values[@]}"
180618 180820
```

or

```
$: eval "alld_values=( $( sed 's/ / $/g' <<< " ${!rundate*}" ) )"
```

or

```
$: echo "alld_values=( $( sed 's/ / $/g' <<< " ${!rundate*}" ) )" > tmp && . tmp
```

Comment: [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) is pertinent. (Granted, the OP's original code runs afoul of that as well).

Comment: Agreed. In fact, the code kind of depends on the very features that open it up to that particular bug. MUCH better to refactor the original code NOT to use the individual variables at all.

Comment: I see you have accepted this solution, but I *strongly* suggest you consider refactoring to an associative array design like that suggested by Charles...

Comment: I accepted your solution(initially) because it was posted first and worked. However, my developing script contains Charles' design. I'm encouraged to know this is what you would suggest.