# How to implement env | grep LANG with fork execve and pipe

Tags: c

I'm writing my minishell and I can't understand why execve doesn't work when calling pid_2 ?
My main task is to implement **env | grep LANG**

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid_1, pid_2;
    int fd[2];
    int status;
    char *mass_1[] = {"env", NULL};
    char *mass_2[] = {"grep", "LANG", NULL};

    pid_1 = fork();
    pipe(fd);
    if (pid_1 == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve(mass_1[0], mass_1, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_2 = fork();
    if (pid_2 == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve(mass_2[0], mass_2, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid_1, &status, WUNTRACED);
    waitpid(pid_2, &status, WUNTRACED);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `dup2(fd[1], 0);` `dup2(fd[0], 0);` Something wrong, you are `dup2` with `0` twice. Shouldn't one of them connect with stdout with `1`?

Comment: `pipe()` after `fork()` is wrong too. That  creates and uses a separate pipe in the first child instead of the one created by the parent

Comment: `env | grep LANG` will also print variables that contain LANG in the value. There are better ways to do that. See [Get list of variables whose name matches a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/511694/995714)

Comment: There's no need to fork and run child processes to access **the environment variables of your own process**. If you're on a POSIX platform, direct access to the entire list of environment variables is done through the `extern char **environ` variable.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html  On Windows, the environment variables are directly available via [the `GetEnvironmentStrings()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentstrings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. `execve()` doesn't search for the command in `$PATH` so generally it won't find neither `env` nor `grep`. Use `execvp()` instead.
2. You should call `pipe()` before the first `fork()` to prevent another pipe to be created and used by the child process
3. as @KamilCuk has pointed out: in the first child process, you should `dup2()` stdout instead of stdin

Fixing these bugs lead to this working code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid_1, pid_2;
    int fd[2];
    int status;
    char *mass_1[] = {"env", NULL};
    char *mass_2[] = {"grep", "LANG", NULL};

    pipe(fd);
    pid_1 = fork();
    if (pid_1 == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(mass_1[0], mass_1);
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_2 = fork();
    if (pid_2 == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(mass_2[0], mass_2);
        exit(1);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid_1, &status, WUNTRACED);
    waitpid(pid_2, &status, WUNTRACED);
    return (0);
}
```

Btw. you should add some error handling e.g. `pipe()` or `fork()` could fail

If you must not call `execvp()` you have to provide pathnames to `execve()` like `"/usr/bin/env"` or `"/bin/grep"`. In this case you also have to provide the parent's environment at least to `env` otherwise it won't print anything.
The easiest way to do so is:

- change the signature of `main()` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`
- call `execve(mass_1[0], mass_1, envp);`

Comment: unfortunately this code is not suitable for me as I only need to use execve but thank you for fixing my errors

Comment: Then you have to find the pathnames of the commands by yourself

Comment: If I specify the paths /bin/env and /bin/grep should work ? it works with execvp but it doesn't work with execve although I have specified the paths to the commands

Comment: Using execve() leads to another problem indeed. Passing NULL as environments leads to `env` not knowing any variables and thus not printing anything. I'm making another edit

Comment: I just added int main(int ac, char * * av, char **env) and add env instead of NULL